# Unique constraint on navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to place a unique constraint on multiple properties on an EF object. One of these properties is an object (navigation property)

```
public class foo
{
    [Key]
    public int FooID {get; set;}
    <other properties here>
}
public class bar
{
    [Key]
    public int barID {get;set;}
    [Index("IX_UniqueWithinFoo", 0, IsUnique = true)]
    public virtual foo parent {get;set;}
    [Index("IX_UniqueWithinFoo", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public int order {get; set;}
}
```

I cant find any documentation to determine if this is the right approach, especially since when inserting the `foo` objects will not equate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this model the EF creates the following tables/indexes/constraints

```
CREATE TABLE [Bars] (
 [barID] int not null identity(1,1)
 , [order] int not null
 , [parent_FooID] int null
);

ALTER TABLE [Bars] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Bars_8873614b] PRIMARY KEY ([barID])

CREATE TABLE [Foos] (
 [FooID] int not null identity(1,1)
);

ALTER TABLE [Foos] ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Foos_8873614b] PRIMARY KEY ([FooID])

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_UniqueWithinFoo] ON [Bars] ([order])

CREATE INDEX [IX_parent_FooID] ON [Bars] ([parent_FooID])

ALTER TABLE [Bars] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Bars_Foos_parent_FooID] FOREIGN KEY ([parent_FooID]) REFERENCES [Foos] ([FooID])
```

Look at the second created index... EF totally ignores index name and unique constraint. I think this could be considered a bug.

If you want to solve the problem you need to insert a property in the class Bar for the relation (at least if you use data annotation) and set the unique index on it.

```
public class Bar
{
    [Key]    
    public int barID {get;set;}

    [Index("IX_UniqueWithinFoo", 0, IsUnique = true)]
    public int parent_FooId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("parent_FooId")]
    public virtual Foo parent { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_UniqueWithinFoo", 1, IsUnique = true)]
    public int order { get; set; }
}
```

In this case only one index is created and the index is

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX [IX_UniqueWithinFoo] ON [Bars] ([parent_FooId], [order])
```

Comment: So in essence, the only way to solve this problem is to add the foreign key property? I can see how it works, but it does seem a little dirty. I'll see if someone has a cleaner solution before ticking as answer, but thanks for the answer!

Comment: There are also 2 other ways. The first is to create index with code migration (I really don't like it). The second (not really a new way, just a way to make the solution above a little bit cleaner) is to make parent_FooId property private and then map it via fluent interface (it must be an inner class inside Bar). At least, Bar users doesn't see the parent_FooId prop...